# Confusion with Task.Run, Task.Wait using CancellationToken

Tags: c#

I have a CancelationTokenSource field in my class

```
CancelationTokenSource cancelSource;
```

I have the following code that ***works*** and it correctly will 'cancel' if i invoke the `cancelSource.Cancel():` or if it times out

```
public byte[] Result()
{
    cancelSource = new CancelationTokenSource(1000); // 1000ms timeout

    Func<Byte[]> f = .. // function that returns a byte[]

    Task<Byte[]> t = Task.Run(f);
    t.Wait(cancelTokenSource.Token);
    return t.Result;
}
```

Then i noticed i can pass the cancelTokenSource.Token directly into the `Task.Run` instead of inside the `Task.Wait()`

```
public byte[] Result()
{
    CancelationTokenSource  = new CancelationTokenSource(1000); // 1000ms timeout

    Func<Byte[]> f = .. // function that returns a byte[]

    Task<Byte[]> t = Task.Run(f, cancelTokenSource.Token);
    t.Wait();
    return t.Result;
}
```

But then when i call `cancelSource.Cancel()`, or after the 1000ms timer,  it just hangs on `Wait()`... Why?

Comment: t.Wait(cancelTokenSource.Token) cancels only the process of waiting for the task, without actually cancelling the task itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passing cancellation token to `Task.Run` and hit `Cancel` then, if task hasn't been started yet and pending on thread pool queue waiting to be executed, it will be removed from queue with state Canceled (read [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run__1_System_Func___0__System_Threading_CancellationToken_)). You can check it by scheduling a lot of tasks and observe that they immediately go to completed state as soon as you cancel them. If you don't pass cancellation token they all have to be executed. In addition, when task runs token, that you passed to `Task.Run`, has to be checked manually like `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` or passed to subsequent tasks to abort execution.

Passing cancellation token to `Wait` as mentioned in comments doesn't cancel task but works pretty much as timeout. If you hit cancel it just stops waiting it to be executed.